# Проверка 2 и более input на disabled

Tags: javascript, input, валидация

Есть 2 инпута, в них вводятся значения, при верном значении input получает disabled.Нужна, проверка в реальном времени, если оба disabled, происходило действие.

```
input.disabled === true && input.disabled === true ? alert(1) : alert(2);
```

Происходит единожды при запуске скрипта, как я понял.

Какие есть еще варианты, кроме через setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логично проверять состояние тогда, когда оно может измениться. Когда в инпуте меняется значение, возникает событие `oninput`. В этом событии можно проверить текущее значение текущего инпута и если оно совпадает с "правильным", заблокировать его и проверить не заблокирован ли второй инпут.

Если у вас инпутов много, то можно присвоить им один класс, а потом при помощи метода `document.querySelectorAll` выбрать все нужные инпуты и проверить их состояние

```js
function check(AInput, ACheckVal) {
  if (AInput.value == ACheckVal) {
    AInput.disabled = true;
    checkOthers();
  }
}

function checkOthers() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (!inputs[i].disabled)
      return;  // Нашли незаблокированный. Выходим
  }
  // Если дошли сюда, то все заблокированы
  console.log('All input disabled');
}
```

```html
<input class="test" oninput="check(this, '1')">
<input class="test" oninput="check(this, '2')">
<input class="test" oninput="check(this, '3')">
<input class="test" oninput="check(this, '4')">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check() {
  if (input1.disabled == true && input2.disabled == true) {
    alert(input1);
    alert(input2);
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="input1" value="" onkeyup="check()">
<input id="input2" value="" onkeyup="check()">
```

Попробуйте так

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется, если эту строчку просто вставить в код, то выполнится она один раз.

```
input.disabled === true && input.disabled === true ? alert(1) : alert(2);
```

Вероятно, стоит производить проверку каждый раз после проверки одного из полей.

> при верном значении input получает disabled

Исходя из вышесказанного я предполагаю, что проверка правильности введенного значения для каждого из полей у вас уже реализована. И, вероятно, производится она в какой-то функции `x`. Соответственно, вам нужно всего лишь добавить в эту функцию `x` проверку на то, что теперь оба поля правильно заполнены, и, если это так, выполнить результирующую функцию - в вашем случае вывести `1`.